# Asp.net application error running with Sitecore 6.4.1

Tags: iis-7.5, sitecore, sitecore6

I have Sitecore as site root (which is running ok) and under it I need to have a bunch of asp.net applications running.

So far, created a virtual directory for the child application, turned it into an app. But as soon as I browse the child app it comes with this error message.

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Sitecore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:



Line 3264:          </providers>
Line 3265:      </roleManager>
Line 3266:      <profile defaultProvider="sql" enabled="true" inherits="Sitecore.Security.UserProfile, Sitecore.Kernel">
Line 3267:          <providers>
Line 3268:              <clear/>
```

It seems that the child asp.net app is inheriting Sitecore settings which are coming from Sitecore web.config.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even though this allowed me to run child asp.net apps and web services under Sitecore website it also broke a few things in Sitecore. For instance rich text editor control would not load. (It's one of the Telerik controls Sitecore uses). As soon as I removed the location tags in Sitecore web.config the error related to Telerik rich text editor went away. So I guess the problem persists, for me at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible. You'll have to author a web.config for that non-Sitecore application in virtual directory, and overwrite the sections under `<system.web>` and `<system.webserver>` which reference Sitecore classes. This includes:

- httpModules / httpHandlers (for these you should "remove all" and add those of that web app)
- security section (put the default ASP.NET provider classes back)
- **in Sitecore main web.config** add the path of this web app to **IgnoreUrlPrefixes** setting to let Sitecore know it should not handle requests to those

It might be something else, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: Perfect, this is the solution. Thanks! Also I used this post for some of the details. http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/05/standalone-apps-under-sitecore-web-root.html

Comment: Good to know! I suggest you subscribe to Alex's blog - there's lots of useful things there :)

Comment: had to rollback to original settings for Sitecore because rich text editor control fail to load in Sitecore. I've left the tags in child asp.net apps for overriding Sitecore settings and values in IgnoreUrlPrefixes but had to remove <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> around <system.web> and <system.webserver>

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is similar to Yan, but is different enough for a separate answer. Hope it helps.*

Go into IIS and select the Child Application. Select Modules. Remove all the Sitecore related modules that are present. Don't worry, the parent Sitecore app will still retain these modules.  [image: Sitecore modules in IIS]

When you do this, you are actually changing the child app web.config, so you will see the elements removed in the web.config file like so.

```xml
<remove name="SitecoreConfigWatcher" />
<remove name="SitecoreHttpModule" />
```

You also may have to clear out some other inherited settings.

```xml
<profile enabled="false"><providers><clear/></providers></profile>
<roleManager enabled="false"><providers><clear /></providers></roleManager>
```